# Save/Load with SharedPreferences at Activity first launch doesn't work

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

At first launch of MainActivity I put this method:

```
startChoice = SharedUtilities.getInstance().getChoice(getApplicationContext());
        if(startChoice ==""){
            start(MainActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class);
        }else{
            ........
}
```

This is method to get the String startChoice

```
public String getChoice(Context context) {
        appSharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("PsiceToday",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        thisChoise = appSharedPrefs.getString("Choice","");
        return thisChoise;
    }
```

The method start(MainActivity.this,RegistrationActivity.class) it's never called because at debug startChoise it's not equals "".

Do you think I have done something wrong in the implementation?

Comment: `startChoice.equals("")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Here is utils class method

```
 public static String ReadSharePrefrence(Context context, String key) {
//        SharedPreferences read_data = context.getSharedPreferences(
//                Constant.SHRED_PR.SHARE_PREF, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//
//        return read_data.getString(key, "");

        String data;
        final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        data = preferences.getString(key, "");
        editor.commit();
        return data;
    }
```

when you want to use it.

```
String value = Utils.ReadSharePrefrence(this,Constant.KEY);
if(value.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
//put your code

}else{
//put your code.

}
```

This was work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [string.equals(Object other)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) function to compare strings, not the == operator.